# Loops and comparing variable values

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, logic

A user inputs a year and it is stored in `year` . And a method is called that calculates and returns the next year that would fall on the same day of the week. The month and day do not change only the year. In this case the month is Jan and the day is 1.

```
/**
 * @param theYear the year given
 */
public int yearSync(int theYear)
{
   int month = 1;
   int day = 1;
   int year = theYear;

   int aMonth = 1;
   int aDay = 1;
   int aYear = year++;

   Date d1 = new Date(month, day, year);
   Date d2 = new Date(aMonth, aDay, aYear);

   boolean valid = false;       

   while (!valid)
   {
      if(d1.getDayOfWeek().equals(d2.getDayOfWeek)))//another class provided is used to 
      {                                             //calc what day of the week it is
         System.out.println(aYear); //prints the year
      }                             //that falls on the same week day as the input year
      else
      {
         aYear++;
      }
   }
   return aYear;
}
```

Not asking for answer just want to know where my error in logic is and what I can do to change my thought process when going about problems such as these. In case there is any confusion, an example would be if I entered 2014, the year returned would be 2020; they both fall on Wednesday.

Edit: changed loop type.

Comment: Note that you have an infinite loop.

Comment: consider using a `while` loop, since you don't know how many iterations it will take to get your answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried a while loop with a boolean value like, `while(!valid)` but i also would get an infinite loop as well. I knew the for loop was infinite, should have mentioned it, my bad.

Comment: it's quite interesting that `i++ >= i` would not even run once, whereas `i <= i++` runs infinitely

Comment: @Claudiu Truly, I did a double take on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop `for (int i = 0; i <= i++; i++)` will never stop ...

The first time through, `i` is set to 0, and the condition is `i < i++`, which will change the value of i to i +1, but the comparison will succeed.

So the first time through the loop, the value of `i` is 1. At the end of the loop it will increment it because of the `i++` (to be the value 2), and then it will compare it again with `i <= i++` which will pass, but will also set i to be 3.

So, the value `i` will be 1, 3, 5, 7, .... in your loops.

This loop condition is pretty bizarre, but, that's not really the problem.... because it is essentially the same as:

```
while (true) {...}
```

The odd part is that when you actually find a year that has the same yad-of-week, you don't then increment the year, i.e. the aYear++ never changes once you find the first match, and then you just repeat the same `System.out.println(...)` forever.

But again, this is all somewhat meaningless because you never change the date value `d2` inside the loop.....

What you want is something like:

```
while(true) {
    aYear++;
    Date d2 = new Date(aMonth, aDay, aYear);
    if (d1.getDayOfWeek().equals(d2.getDayOfWeek)))//another class provided is used to 
    {                                             //calc what day of the week it is
        System.out.println(aYear); //prints the year
        return aYear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed `aYear` would never update, it didn't occur to me to create a `Date` object in the loop itself. So why would creating a second `Date` object out side the loop prevent `aYear` from updating normally?

Answer (score 0):

You are just incrementing the `aYear` variable but `d2` reference will always hold the `aYear` initial value as it was created with. So you need to update `d2` reference also in your for loop to have the next year with each loop iteration.

Also you need to break the loop once you find the desired year. Here is the updated for loop, hope it works:

```
 //for sake of this question I will use a for loop
   for (int i = 0; i <= i++; i++)
   {
      if(d1.getDayOfWeek().equals(d2.getDayOfWeek)))//another class provided is used to 
      {                                             //calc what day of the week it is
         System.out.println(aYear); //prints the year
         break;
      }                             //that falls on the same week day as the input year
      else
      {
         aYear++;
      }
      d2 = new Date(aMonth, aDay, aYear);
   }
   return aYear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, your loop will go on forever. You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= i++; i++) { ... }
```

This is equivalent to:

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= i++) {
    ...
}
```

What `i++` does is it evaluates to `i`, and the increments `i` by one. To make it even more obvious let's unpack what `i++` is doing into multiple statements:

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    //left-hand-side is 'i'
    int leftHandSide = i;
    //right-hand-side is 'i++' which evaluates to 'i' and then 'i' is incremented
    int rightHandSide = i;
    i += 1;
    if (leftHandSide <= rightHandSide) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you notice this just ends up comparing `i <= i`, which is always true, so the loop will never break.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find matching values from two arrays. add getDayofWeek() and whatever else you need.

```
     for(int x : d1){

         //Some counter = 0;  

        for(int y : d2) {  
           if(x.equals(y))
           //counter++;
       }
        System.out.println(y);

       }}
```